# What would be the proper mental model helpful in understanding of bash redirection?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

What would be a consistent explanation of the mechanisms which result in a following bash session logs helpful in gaining understanding and making reliable prediction of outcomes for similar constructed commands possible:

```bash
~ $ cat f
abc123
~ $ cat g
cat: g: No such file or directory
~ $ cat f g 2>&1 >h
cat: g: No such file or directory
~ $ cat h
abc123
```

and

```bash
~ $ cmd >a 2>&1
~ $ cat a
Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 19 similar ones.
~ $ cmd 2>&1 >a
Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 19 similar ones.
~ $ cat a
~ $
```

and

```
~ $ echo abc > a; echo bcd > b; echo cde > c
~ $ cat a
abc
~ $ cat b
bcd
~ $ cat c
cde
~ $ cmd >a>b>c 2>&1
~ $ cat a
~ $ cat b
~ $ cat c
Command 'cmd' not found, but there are 19 similar ones.
```

?

Have you succeeded in correctly predicting the outcome of the commands above in advance? If yes, how did you arrive at the right prediction?

Comment: You can start building your mental model with "the order of redirections matters". From `bash` manual: "_Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right._" In the same manual have a look maybe at the first example which is exactly your example.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : yes, I have been through that manual ... but the manual does not explain it clearly enough to build a mental model of how it works. I can see the outcome, but I fail to build a mental model out of it in the context of overall understanding of what redirection is. ChatGPT has read that manual too ... and fails to predict the outcome not able to provide correct explanation for the observed behavior contradicting itself depending on what is asked for. So ... if you can provide an explanation able to explain it without contradicting itself ... please write an answer.

Comment: Well, proposing a mental model for somebody else is not easy but here is a suggestion: you can consider all redirections, from left to right, as a sequence of instructions. In your first example the instructions are: `stdout = a; stderr = stdout`. In most programming languages, after executing this, you have `stdout = stderr = a`, reason why both the standard output and standard error are redirected to file `a`.

Comment: In your second example the instructions are: `stderr = stdout; stdout = a`. The standard error is redirected to whatever `stdout` was (your terminal maybe), before the second instruction is executed, and then the standard output is redirected to file `a`. Not sure it helps, the efficiency of this kind of mental model strongly depends on the way your brain likes representing things.

Comment: Note: I will not write an answer because 1) my proposal is far from complete and 2) your question is maybe a bit borderline for SO. Not really a programming question but not completely out of scope. I let others decide and answer if they wish.

Comment: You post several commands, some with and some without redirection. In particular, none of the error messages you received is related to redirection. Focus on one command at a time and ask about this, and if you have understood, proceed to the next one.

Comment: what don't you understand about the results of the two command sequences you show?

Comment: @jhnc : for example: `cmd 2>&1 >a` left to right ... cmd is executed and throws an error, the stderr is redirected to stdout and the standard out is redirected to file a, so the error message should be written to file a, but it doesn't ... it is written to Terminal stdout and nothing is written to a. Now `cmd > a 2>&1` left to right: cmd does not create anything on stdout so nothing is written to file a then stderr is redirected to stdout (of the Terminal) and need to appear there - but it does not, it is written to file a . So there is something wrong in the mental model of it.

Comment: You are conflating the name and the value. `2>&1` does not mean redirect stderr to stdout. It means redirect stderr to wherever stdout is currently going. Perhaps use the analogy of hosepipes feeding into basins - you are moving the ends of the hosepipes

Comment: @jhnc: `2>&1` The default behavior without it is: 2 goes to terminal and 1 goes to terminal, so `2>&1` has no effect at all , both hosepipes go to the terminal as before, so `cmd 2>&1` is equivalent to `cmd` - a redirection without any effect at all? Then if I take 1 and put it to file a, the 2 will stay at the terminal because 2 is not feeded into 1 as hosepipe but to the basin being the terminal?

Comment: Probably not far from truth is the assumption that the number of downvotes mirrors the number of people with weak understanding of the English language, of the question and of the mechanism of redirection now considering the question to be bad and worth to be punished away, isn't it?

Comment: `cmd is executed and throws an error, the stderr is redirected to stdout` You mean the "cmd: command not found" error? It is not an error from `cmd`, `cmd` was not executed. It is an error from bash, and bash stderr is pointing to the terminal.

Comment: @KamilCuk : yes ... it's so easy even if knowing it somehow already, but not clearly enough to express it properly while speaking about it. Thanks for pointing it out. By the way: where are the executable itself stdout and stderr pointing to? Probably to bash ... not to the terminal ...?

Comment: Which parts of the ouputs you pressented is unclear to you? How does it differ from what you expect or which outputs are unclear to you? I think this question is "too vague", there is no "mental model", or maybe the "mental model" is subjective and what fits reality. Could you ask a specific question to a specific lines of output you presented in the question?

Comment: `Could you ask a specific question to a specific lines of output you presented in the question?` it would make no sense to do it ... I am looking for an explanation I can then check if it covers all of the myriads of possible cases - so narrowing it down to one or two cases does not make much sense ... It's not useful to get an explanation for two individual cases which then does not work for millions of other ones because simplified, or bad worded or just wrong.

Comment: I would be glad to see an answer where someone explains his/her way of thinking while predicting the output of a command using many redirections clearly enough to be followed and used to check if it works and covers the full range of possible edge cases I am able to come up with.

Comment: @Claudio Did you read my comments above and if yes what is still unclear about the behavior you observe with your 2 examples?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : in order to understand how things work it is necessary to cover with a mental model all possible cases one can come up with. If I limit myself to two cases, observe what they do and accept that it is OK what they do, I can memorize the cases and stop - it's clear what they do, so what? No need to think any step further. I will add a third case which needs explanation to hopefully make it understandable what I am after ...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : based on your up to now comments I have constructed a third case. Were you able to predict the outcome of the final command correctly using the way of explaining what is going on described in your previous comments? If yes, what was your chain of deduction leading to the correct result?

Comment: @Claudio I see. If you stick with my model (`stdout = a; stdout = b; stdout = c; stderr = stdout`) you should understand why after all these redirections `stderr = stdout = c` and why the `bash` error message about the not found `cmd` command is sent to file `c`. What's missing is why `a` and `b` are emptied. Simple: when you execute `>file`, `file` is opened for writing and (bash manual) "_If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size_". So even if later redirections cancels it, the effect of `>file` is to empty `file`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : OK ... the third case explained, but ... it seems that the mental model of hosepipes and bassins is simpler to adopt than the more abstract approach staying with the pipes and not mentioning the bassins. At the current moment it appears that the hosepipe/bassin based mental model extended with the rule that putting a hosepipe into a bassin is enough to empty the bassin (but putting it to the terminal won't clear its display ... why?) seems to be able to come up with the right predictions ... now it's time to look for counter-examples ...

Comment: The mental model I suggest is not based on pipes. It is based on one of the simplest principles of most imperative programming languages: sequential variable assignments. Just read `>file` as `stdout = file`, `2>&1` as `stderr = stdout` and you're done. If you play with other file descriptors simply remember that `stdin, stdout, stderr` are aliases for `fd0, fd1, fd2`, respectively. The other file descriptors don't have an alias. `3>&1` reads as `fd3 = stdout` and is a way, for instance, to store the current state of `stdout`, in order to restore it later, after some redirection.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Hmmm .... let me some time to "digest" your way of looking at it ... Currently if I let the 'bassins" out of consideration I run into trouble ... it's not an assignment to a file descriptor only because it can have side-effects ... you need to consider the target to see why a file will be emptied but a terminal not cleared  ... so you need the `bassins` ... pipes or assignments alone seem not enough ...

Comment: @Claudio OK, if you prefer pipes and bassins, it's fine. Good luck with your plumbing ;-)

Comment: "Have you succeeded in correctly predicting the outcome of the commands above in advance? If yes, how did you arrive at the right prediction?" - sounds like a high school math test.

Comment: I would hope you might find https://web.archive.org/web/20230412163832/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial helpful. Note in particular the "order of redirection" section. Or, as a quicker/terser/shorter document, https://web.archive.org/web/20230208032810/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/copydescriptor. As another alternative, [BashFAQ #55](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055).

Comment: It's honestly unclear to me what this question asks that preexisting documentation doesn't handle -- if there's a _specific_ gap, focusing on it would make for a narrower question (thus, one which the "too broad" close reason can't be argued to fit).

Comment: Yes ... it's extremely hard to understand what can be wrong with understanding of someone else if you forgot on the way to own understanding the issues you needed to overcome yourself. It's a kind of retrospective retrospection needed here ... a skill hard to acquire. I took a look at all the links you have provided. Now ... after I already know how it goes I can see that it is there ... but not before. You can test it using ChatGPT ... if ChatGPT has a clear "understanding" the tutorials are suitable to convey understanding. If ChatGPT screws everything ... one will be lost too.

Comment: By the way: it is probably not true that the output of stdout and stderr of a script or command goes to the Terminal ... I suppose they go to the shell first and the shell forwards them to the terminal. And the terminal then decides if it will show it or not. Once you start to believe that stdout goes to the display of the Terminal you will be lost later after digging deeper wondering how it comes that output does not show up ...

Comment: I am not really satisfied with the answers ... The question does not need more focus ... it does need better answers ... blocked by being provided because closed ...  so please just re-open ... it does make much more sense than keeping it closed ... by this amount of views in so short time sure worth getting better answers ...

Comment: No, stdout and stderr are not relayed to the shell unless you go out of your way to force them to. When you run `./yourprogram`, that subprocess inherits all the file descriptors its parent had -- if the shell's own stdin, stdout and stderr were connected to the terminal, yourprogram's communications go directly there without the shell being involved in consuming or relaying them at all.

Comment: An example of forcing stdout to go to the shell instead of to the terminal would be `output=$(./yourprogram)`, which tells the shell to create a FIFO and, after forking off a child process (which will be replaced with `./yourprogram` via an execve syscall), connect stdout of the new child to the write side of that FIFO (while the parent process connects to the read side of the FIFO to consume output from there).

Comment: The problem with trying to gage from ChatGPT what the quality of the tutorials is is that ChatGPT's recall is only suitable for serious work when it's doing retrieval-augmented generation with good input.

Comment: If you use the gpt-4-turbo model with its 128kilotoken context window and put the tutorial itself in the context window alongside your question, _then_ you can judge whether the tutorial answers the question, but not before: otherwise its memory is a mismash; maybe the tutorials got spidered, but so did a bunch of inaccurate mistakes by Internet randos badly explaining concepts they didn't understand themselves.

Comment: OK ... I am on the free tier with ChatGPT 3 ... with limited size of context. The general issue is my individual inner "language". Once you give in and start thinking as suggested by the tutorials you will fail to understand the issues they come with. Somehow I am rejecting to surrender and give up my own inner "language" ready only for the effort to learn expressing myself using English - which should be enough for both purposes: conveying the ideas and being compiled into machine code. The latter would make tutorials and documentation obsolete as the code will be the documentation.

Comment: The goal of the oOo way of approaching programming and computers is to make the system understand what is said instead of forcing you to learn how to speak to the system in order to be understood. The computation power required to achieve this is there ... but the awareness is not there that this is the better way - maybe because it will render all the experts experience obsolete - hence the resistance against adopting such guidelines in programming by the knowledgeable fearing to loose their expert status.

Comment: Closing such questions  as this one I have asked is a quite good example of resistance ... instead of providing better explanations the experts point to the tutorials ... partially no more able to understand how the tutorials screwed their own way of thinking and why the tutorials are so hard to read for someone not ready to screw oneself into it too. Instead of excellent demonstration in code by smart choices of use cases there are pages of explanations ... focusing on all, but not on understanding of the core concepts ...

Comment: Imagine you try to explain in the middle of summer to someone who never experienced a snowfall and is not aware of existence of strong winds and much snow what is the snow fence along the highway good for ... Without showing what a snowfall is and how can it block the highway you may speak many words about protection from being blocked and the construction details of such fences without the slightest chance of being understood. For you it is clear that's because of snowfall and the wind... so you just forget to mention it ... feeling angry how it comes that your explanation appears useless ...

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the proper mental model helpful in understanding of bash redirection?

As I read through the comments, I will guess you become confused at how *file descriptors* are not files, but really pointers to handles to files.

The "mental model" of file descriptors is really explained in many places, even on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor . File descriptor is a pointer to filetable of inode table (like a double pointer). Consider researching what is a file descriptor and how it works.

> cmd 2>&1 >a left to right ... cmd is executed and throws an error, the stderr is redirected to stdout and the standard out is redirected to file a, so the error message should be written to file a, but it doesn'

They are pointers. At `2>&1` stderr is redirect to where stdout *is* pointing. Then `>a` is *opening* file `a`, creating entry in filetable, and redirecting stdout to that entry in filetable. Stderr is still *pointing* to the entry in filetable stdout *was* pointing at the time `2>&1` *was* created.

> where are the executable itself stdout and stderr pointing to?

The file descriptors are inherited from the parent process. Bash (or any parent process) file descriptors point to somewhere, when creating a child process all file descriptors are copied and point to the same somewhere.

Related: `man dup2`, `man clone`, `man fork`, `man exec`. I really understood what is `fd` after I understood how `flock` works.

Also, don't trust me! You can observe what a process is doing with `strace`.

```
$ LC_ALL=C strace -ff -e open,openat,clone,dup2,write bash -c 'cmd 2>&1 >/tmp/a'
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libreadline.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7afe089c6e50) = 90612
strace: Process 90612 attached
[pid 90612] dup2(1, 2)                  = 2
[pid 90612] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 90612] dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
[pid 90612] write(2, "bash: line 1: cmd: command not f"..., 37bash: line 1: cmd: command not found
) = 37
[pid 90612] +++ exited with 127 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=90612, si_uid=1000, si_status=127, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

> May you explain why the outcome of dup2(1,2) followed by dup2(3, 1) is another one when I switch their order?

Let's try! Let's assume we have the following input state at some program initialization, after the process has started and opened a `/tmp/a` file with file descriptor `3`/

[image]

1. First case:

   1. Execute `dup2(1, 2)`. Nothing happens. `2` already points to `/dev/tty`.
   2. Then execute `dup2(3, 1)`. Below is the resulting connection. `2` still points to `/dev/tty`, but `1` was moved to `/tmp/a`.

      [image]
2. Second case:

   1. Execute `dup2(3, 1)`, so we move `1` arrow to where `3` is pointing. Below is the result:

      [image]
   2. Then execute `dup2(1, 2)`, so we move `2` to where `1` is pointing to.

      [image]

As you see, the result is different. In the `dup2(3, 1); dup2(1, 2)` case, all `1` `2` and `3` file descriptors point to `/tmp/a`. In contrast, in the `dup2(1, 2); dup2(3, 1)`, the `2` is still pointing to `/dev/tty`.

The images above are missing the "file table" pointers, because I am too lazy to draw it. It would be just `[0,1,2] -> readwrite -> /dev/tty` and `3 -> read -> /tmp/a`, for simplicity.

Let's do also this:

> Have you succeeded in correctly predicting the outcome of the commands above in advance? If yes, how did you arrive at the right prediction?

```
~ $ cat f g 2>&1 >h
```

The `2>&1` will make stderr output on terminal. Then `>h`, so stdout goes to `h`. The content of file `f` will be in file `h`. The error message will be on terminal.

```
~ $ cmd >a 2>&1
```

The output of command `cmd` will go to `a`. Then stderr will also go to `a`. `cmd` does not exists. Bash will spawn a child process, then try to execute `cmd`. Bash will fail, so the Bash child temporary subshell will print an error message to file `a`.

```
~ $ cmd 2>&1 >a
```

As above in the `2>&1 >h` case. Just the message does not come from `cat`, but from the temporary subshell Bash spawns to exec `cmd`.

```
~ $ cmd >a>b>c 2>&1
```

Is equal to `cmd >a >b >c 2>&1`. First, stdout goes to `a`. Then file descriptor that references file `a` is closed, and stdout goes to another file descriptor coming from opening file `b`. Then `b` is closed, and stdout goes to `c`. Then stderr also goes to `c`. The error message about `cmd: command not found` will be in `c`, as the temporary subshell will print it to `stderr` which points to `c` now. Because `>` `open()`s files with `O_CREAT`, there will be empty files `a` and `b`.

---

That was easy. Now me! Let's throw my examples. We have a function, that outputs `stdout` to stdout and `stderr` to stderr.

```
output() { echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; }
```

Then we take the magic `time`. `time` is a shell built-in. `time` outputs the timing message *from the parent shell*, *not* from the child subshell Bash spawns when executing the command. This is *in contrast* to the `cmd: command not found` message, which is outputted by the child subshell spawned to execute `cmd`. `time` message is printed *by the parent shell* after the child exits.

What is the output of the following commands? What output is outputted to stdout? And what output is on stderr?

1. `output 3>&2 1>&2 2>&3`
2. `output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`
3. `var=$(output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3); echo "VAR: $var"`
4. `var=$(output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) 2>/dev/null; echo "VAR: $var"`
5. `{ var=$(output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3); } 2>/dev/null; echo "VAR: $var"`
6. `time output >/dev/null 2>&1`
7. `( time output 2>&1 ) >/dev/null`
8. `{ time output 2>&1; } 2>&1 >/dev/null`
9. `var=$( { time output 2>&1; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ); echo "TIME: $var"`
10. `exec 3>&1; var=$( { time output >&3 2>&1; } 2>&1 ); echo "TIME: $var"`
11. `var=$( { time output 2>&1; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ) 2>&1; echo "TIME: $var"`
12. `{ var=$( { time output 2>&1; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ); } 2>&1; echo "TIME: $var"`

Comment: Thank you much for your response. It's an explanation at another level as the level I was seeking an answer, but very interesting one. May you explain why the outcome of `dup2(1,2)` followed by `dup2(3, 1)` is another one when I switch their order?

Comment: note that the shell will get confused if you leave out spaces and try `cmd >1>2>3 2>&1`

Comment: Hi `I don't think this is exact`  what is not exact about that? Yes, that is true. Linux programs do `fork+exec` to execute anything. First, Bash executes `fork`, which is the `clone()` system call in `strace` output. After `fork`, there is Bash parent and Bash child. Then Bash saerches entries in `PATH` to find `cmd` and then will try to `exec` it. Executable `cmd` is not in PATH, the search fails. The child Bash process prints an error message and exits. Compare with `strace` output.

Comment: A bit of trivia on `fork+exec`, it is the super very standard method of spawning processes in Linux since the very beginning. This is in strong comparison with Windows that has completely different model, which is one of the sources of incompatibility of Linux programs to Windows. Newer POSIX introduced `posix_spawn` function to deal with missing `fork` on some platforms. Internally on `glibc` the `posix_spawn` is anyway implemented with `fork+exec`.

Comment: @jhnc : yes ... leaving out spaces in >a>b>c is 'dirty'. I am wondering why the shell does not complain in case of `>f` with `>f not found` as the command file name can be composed of any Unicode character. There are some characters causing side-effects like semicolon or newline. So `>` is a problem in a file name of an executable ... Same with `(` and `)`. If there is a quotation mark in the command name it is not taken literally ... many things to consider if you want the freedom of naming executable files. From my perspective something missed to be changed with advent of Unicode ...

Comment: Hi @Claudio I do not understand the above comment, I suspect it references some in existing comment. I do not consider `>a>b>c` dirty, and I do not understand the comment resolution. You can name your executables anyhow you want, including any sequence of bytes, including unicode and any non-unicode. Neither `>` or `)` or `(` are not a problem in executable files. They would require specifically _in shell_ escaping or quotes, which is specific to the POSIX shell and how shell parses user input. Such characters would not require any special escaping in python or C for example.

Comment: @KamilCuk : The reference for the comment is: `>>note that the shell will get confused if you leave out spaces and try cmd >1>2>3 2>&1 – *jhnc*` - meaning the code `cmd a>b>c` in the question - spaces are not needed here to separate redirections - a quite deliberate choice by the shell programmers, right?

Comment: `deliberate choice` Shell was created 40 years ago. I do not think it is "deliberate" here, it just depends on how Ritchie was feeling about it when writing SVR. You can see standarized POSIX shell syntax https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02

Comment: I am now fully lost: `output 3>&2 1>&2 2>&3` does not result in an error stating that 3 is not known ... what tfk is 3???

Comment: As I explained, `3>&2` reads as `fd3 = stderr` and is, for instance, a way to store the current state of `stderr` in file descriptor number 3, and restore it after some other redirections. In this case the sequence is: `fd3 = stderr; stdout = stderr; stderr = fd3`. Not very useful, but valid.

Comment: There are many ways to create new file descriptors. You can copy existing file descriptor, bottom line, it's just a pointer. As usual, see `man dup2`.

Comment: Must be something with your shell. `output() { echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; }; output 3>&2 1>&2 2>&3` outputs `stderr stdout`. Tested on https://onlinegdb.com/o2wfEQ2O7 . Might be also that you are not using Bash.

Comment: I do not understand what has been written above. Echo is bash builtin, its buffering depends on Bash process, but I think it shouldn't be ever buffered, otherwise `echo -n` wouldn't work. You can instead use `printf`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215669/how-to-ensure-proper-order-of-outputs-to-stdout-and-stderr-in-a-linux-shell-das for the issue I have faced while scripting the "riddles" you have listed in your answer.

Comment: @KamilCuk : are you sure that stdout and stderr go to /dev/tty and not to the shell process running within the Terminal Emulator and from there to the Terminal where the Terminal displays what the shell requested or just doesn't because of some own internal settings valid at the moment of getting the request to display some data?

Comment: Hi, I do not understand the question. You can inspect file descriptors of a _specific_ process at `/proc/<PID>/fd/`. Any process may have stdout and stdout connected to anywhere, some specific process may or may not have stdout and stderr connected to /dev/tty, there is no general answer. I am not sure and not anyhow inferring that some your specific process is connected to anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

In the spirit of the oOo way of doing things (check out my profile for more) I suggest that you arrange for yourself a test environment like this one you can see in the image below. While running screenkey it consists of three kakoune text editor windows, a Terminal and the Thunar file manager window tracking the state of current directory of the shell session where kakoune instantly updates content of the by shell commands affected files. Such setting will help you to find out yourself how things work by creative usage of various commands while observing the details of the outcome in instantly their content updating windows.

[image: testEnvironmentSetup]

The image above captures a frame of a video which addresses the explanation how it comes that the files a and b are emptied and only file c is filled with content where the next command `>a>b>c` will empty the files a, b and c:

[image: testEnvSettingFinalFrame]

---

The trouble you face while trying to understand the first two cases posted in your question is rooted in the wrong assumption that redirection can be explained with a model of hosepipes and redirecting stderr to stdout means to let the stderr pipe pump its water into the stdout pipe.

*Generally said it is sure not a wrong advice to refrain from believing that the online available tutorials and the pictures they provide on this subject are a true and correct explanation.*
It is a good right of free speech to put own weak understanding of the subject combined with bad choices of words to describe something online. It is YOU who need to approach the online available tutorials with appropriate amount of doubt about their correctness.

The widespread wording that the expression `2>&1` describes a redirection of stderr to stdout is not only misleading, but just not true. So how does it come that it stays a valid mainstream description? Hard to guess ... maybe because no one really cares?
You may ask: 'if the mainstream description is not true, what is then true'? I don't know ... all what I can say is that stating it following way will be more correct:

*`2>&1` is a statement involving data streams called stderr and stdout where a data stream is a concept involving a target for this data stream which will receive the data written to this stream. The target of the data stream can be considered a value of what is named stdout, stderr or using the numeric aliases of these names 1 and 2. The numeric aliases are what can lead to the impression that 1 is the value of stdout and 2 the value of stderr, but the actual value of stdout alias 1 and stderr alias 2 is actually a pointer to the recipient of the data.

#### There is no redirection of one stream into another stream ... what actually really happens is an assignment of a new target to a stream described in terms of a target used by another stream at the moment of assignment.

If you change your mental model to another one, like suggested in the comment to your question by *jhnc*, where redirection is putting the hosepipe into a basin and redirecting stderr to stdout means to put the stderr pipe into the basin where the stdout pipe was placed at the current moment at which the redirecting takes place while evaluating a command from left to the right it will allow you to predict the correct result in the first two cases.

The hosepipe/basin mental model does not provide the right prediction in the third case, so it needs some improvement to cover also this case. The improvement consists of becoming aware that putting a hosepipe into a basin using `>` ( instead of `>>` ) actually, like suggested in the comment by *Renaud Pacalet* , empties the basin if there is no water in the hosepipe. In other words a hosepipe is in case of a file as its target able to fill the "basin" with emptiness if there is no "water" in the pipe to put there.

What still maybe remains unexplained is why putting the hosepipe into the 'basin' of the terminal does not empty it in first place? It seems that the mental model of existence of a Terminal 'basin' need to be refined taking the shell into consideration.

The in the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) [image: articleImage] provided image is not helpful here and **an excellent example how you can badly screw your understanding if you consider the by the image provided information as correct.**

Let's apply the suggested pipe/basin mental model to explain the outcome of the in the other answer suggested "riddles":

```
true ' stdin, stdout, stderr are file descriptor names: 
        /dev/stderr
        /dev/stdin
        /dev/stdout
which point (do they???) to the same ressources than
        /dev/fd/0
        /dev/fd/1
        /dev/fd/2
BUT ... each application gets own stdin, stdout and stderr specific to this application.        '

# Let’s define a function, that outputs  "stdout"  to stdout and  "stderr"  to stderr.
output() { printf 'stdout '   ;  printf 'stderr ' >&2  ; echo ;  }
˙ ' The function   output   streams  the word ’stdout’ to the pipe called ’1’ ( alias stdout ),
     the word ’stderr’ to the pipe called ’2’  ( alias stderr ) and the newline to  pipe    ’1’         '

˙  'What will be  the output of the following commands? '
echo '--1--'; output    3>&2    1>&2    2>&3    | grep --color std
echo '--2--'; output    3>&1    1>&2    2>&3    | grep --color std
echo '--3--'; output    3>&1    2>&1    1>&3    | grep --color std
# Let’s explain the most interesting output '--2--' using the pipe/basin mental model knowing that   grep --color  is highlighting only the stdout part of incoming input:
#       --2--
#       stdout      --> NOTICE: ’ std’ will appear in same default color as ’out’
#       stderr      --> NOTICE: ’ std’ will appear colored / highlighted
#echo '--2--'; output   3>&1    1>&2    2>&3    | grep --color std
#                   ^-- 3>&1 : a pipe ’3’ (existing or created) is put into the basin with  pipe 1 (alias stdout)  which is at that moment this part of the shell which awaits input from stdout. 
#                           ^-- 1>&2 : pipe called ’1’ (alias stdout) is put to the basin with pipe 2 i.e. targeting the stderr part of shell input.
#                                   ^-- 2>&3 : pipe ’2’ (alias stderr) is put where pipe 3 is at the current moment and this is the part of the shell which awaits input from stdout
#           ^-- the function streams the word  ’stdout’ via pipe ’1’ (alias stdout) to the stderr part of shell input to become  finally echoed in Terminal WITHOUT COLORING
#               and then streams the word ’stderr’ into via pipe ’2’ (alias stderr) to the part of the shell which awaits input from stdin echoed to Terminal WITH COLORING
#   The line feed between stdout and stderr is caused by streaming the newline via pipe 1 after the word  'stdout'  to stderr
echo '--4--'
 var=$(output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3); echo "var: $var"
 # using a variable var and $(...) allows to separate the stdout and stderr parts of  output because only stdout part of the final output goes to the variable var 
 #  with help of pipe 3 the stdout and stderr are switched, so that the word 'stderr' arrives at the variable and the word 'stdout' is printed to the Terminal (i.e. stderr part of shell input) 
 #      with help of this construct the stdout and stderr parts can be distinguished like it was done using grep coloring
echo '--5--'
var=$(output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3) 2>/dev/null; echo "var: $var"
# has the same effect than --4-- because the variable assignment is evaluated prior to 2>/dev/null  so that it has no effect here
echo '--6--'
{ var=$(output 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3); } 2>/dev/null; echo "VAR: $var"
# now 2>/dev/null is taken into the context of output related to expression within {...} and "swallows" the word 'stdout' so that it does not appear in the output
echo '--7-- '
time output >/dev/null 2>&1
# first the pipe 1 of stdout is put to the nowhere bassin, then pipe 2 of stderr to where pipe 1 is and this is nowhere. The time command is not affected by any redirections here.
echo '--8--'
( time output 2>&1 ) >/dev/null 
# even putting time into a group does not change anything about the time output because time outputs on stderr
echo '--9--'
{ time output 2>&1; } 2>&1 >/dev/null
# time output will stay there because stderr was put on shell stdout input  before stdout is put into nowhere
echo '--10--'
var=$( { time output 2>&1; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ); echo "TIME: $var"
# the variable is not set because the outcome of  output  is encapsulated and goes to shell first before it arrives as in the context of $(... )
echo '--11--'
exec 3>&1; var=$( { time output >&3 2>&1; } 2>&1 ); echo "TIME: $var"
# same as --10--  no of the stream assignments (redirections) has any effect on the outcome
echo ' --12-- '
var=$( { time output 2>&1; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ) 2>&1; echo "TIME: $var"
# same as --10--  no of the stream assignments (redirections) has any effect on the outcome
echo '--13--'
{ var=$( { time output 2>&1; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 ); } 2>&1; echo "TIME: $var"
# same as --10--  no of the stream assignments (redirections) has any effect on the outcome
echo '==  =='
```

considering the comments in the script and the output:

```
~ $ ./_oo--shPrgLang--_O--pipeBasin-mentalModel-forUnderstanding-shellRedirection--_oo0.sh
--1--
stdout stderr 
--2--
stdout 
stderr 
--3--
stdout stderr 
--4--
stdout 
var: stderr 
--5--
stdout 
var: stderr 
--6--
VAR: stderr 
--7-- 

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
--8--

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
--9--

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
--10--
stdout stderr 
TIME: 
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
--11--
stdout stderr 
TIME: 
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
 --12-- 
stdout stderr 
TIME: 
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
--13--
stdout stderr 
TIME: 
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
==  ==
```

it appears that the pipe/basin mental model is suitable for use in explanation of effects of redirections if coupled with appropriate deep know-how related to further constructs available in shell scripting.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : thanks for reading :)  and detecting the issue I have already corrected while adding further content to the text ...

Comment: Your terminal is not a file. It is a complex application with its own standard input, output, error, and its own logic. In UNIX-like systems "_everything is a file_" but not the applications themselves, only the way they receive inputs from other applications and transmit outputs to other applications. If you want to clear the main graphical panel of your terminal you must read its documentation and use the right command, select the right menu item or click on the right icon.

Comment: Hmmm ... but the terminal behaves very similar to a file ... in the application I write to it like I write to a file ... and the terminal gets it ... what I see on the display in the terminal window ... this is another story ... but generally a terminal is the target 'file' I use in the application to write content to, right?

Comment: No, not at all, applications are not files and they don't behave as files. You can send an audio stream to your music player but you cannot "empty" the sounds that have already been played even if you play with redirections. Anyway, if you prefer considering applications as files it's fine. I am pretty sure this analogy will quickly hit its limits and that it will probably make your "mental model" of redirections much more complicated, if not impossible, but as long as you're happy with it....

Comment: ITYM [`basin`](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/basin), not `bassin`. Regarding "why putting the hosepipe into the 'bassin' of the terminal does not empty it in first place?" - a basin doesn't become empty when you put a hosepipe in it.

Comment: @EdMorton : with `>f` I am putting a hosepipe into a bassin of bytes making up the content of a file `f` and the result is that the file gets empty ... redirection is a wrong word here, because if there is nothing to redirect in an empty hosepipe ... the hosepipe fills the bassin with its emptiness ... draining the water if there is some there. By the way: if the concept of redirection would be properly explained by in Internet available content, I would not need to ask here ... ChatGPT would explain it to me better than a human author could do, but ... ChatGPT fails horribly on this ...

Comment: You're trying to come up with a real world analogy and I appreciate that as it does make software concepts easier to grasp if you can relate them to the real world, but putting a hosepipe into a basin of water in the real world does not cause the basin to empty (unless there's a sump pump at the other end of the pipe sucking the water out but that doesn't fit this scenario either) so the analogy doesn't work.

Comment: As for ChatGPT, a good analogy for it's software answers at least would be if you had a friend who'd read a lot of books but didn't really understand what they were reading and then every time you asked them a question they gave you an answer that sounded very convincing as it contained a lot of facts from those books (that may not actually make sense together) and provided a bunch of references (which were almost all wrong but you aren't going to look them up) and so you go away thinking you got a good answer when in fact you didn't.

Comment: You may be interested in [chatgpt-answers-more-than-half-of-software-engineering-questions-incorrectly/](https://www.zdnet.com/article/chatgpt-answers-more-than-half-of-software-engineering-questions-incorrectly/).

Comment: I just went to ChatGPT and asked it "how do I remove the oldest file in my directory using bash" and it gave me an answer that had the wrong shebang, didn't test for `cd` succeeding (so if the directory wasnt readable youd rm a file from the wrong directory), was parsing the output of `ls -t` (never do that, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), was calling `rm` without `--` so it'd fail if the name started with `-`, would attempt to remove a directory instead of a file if it was older, and doesnt test for succ/fail before printing a success message. Almost more errors than lines of code

Comment: @EdMorton : ChatGPT responses are instant, so it is still worth a try. Even if you need to throw 70% away, 30% will be correct including consideration of things you yourself have missed to consider. The trouble with shell redirection is that ChatGPT goes fully crazy here. From my perspective an evidence that there is no well formulated manual on this online. The better something is already documented the higher chance to get a right answer. ChatGPT is perfect at understanding English ... but most authors of tutorials and manuals are not ... what leads to trouble with ChatGPT answers.

Comment: @EdMorton : the hosepipe analogy works ok ... you need to accept that if you use `>` instead of `>>` the hosepipe will fill the bassin with what is in the pipe. If the pipe is empty ... the bassin will be filled up with emptiness ...

Comment: If you say so... All the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257238/discussion-between-claudio-and-ed-morton).

Comment: Re: ChatGPT -- how do you know _which_ 30% is correct if you don't have enough expertise to not need to ask the question in the first place? Particularly in bash, there are a lot of places where an incorrect understanding can look plausibly correct until you stumble into a corner case. If you're lucky that corner case won't involve security flaws or data loss.

Comment: If I ask the question I have usually enough expertise to be able to see which 30% is correct. If I am not sure, because of lack of understanding, I ask ChatGPT for detailed explanation until I arrive at own understanding. Running the code provided by ChatGPT without taking full responsibility for it outcome oneself can be a disaster ... I did it once ... to speed up my progress ... and was thrown back one day and needed to reinstall the entire system which couldn't even be rescued from backup done by timeshift. Yes ... it's always risky ... but it's the same with answers on stackoverflow ...

Comment: At least with Stack Overflow it's possible to track answers down to individual humans who have individual track records and areas of expertise. For example, if Ed contradicts me on something related to awk, I'm probably wrong. By contrast, with ChatGPT you're getting an average of what random people on the Internet tend to write, and the average person writing shell scripts (or even trying to explain shell behavior) _has no clue what they're doing_. Even published books on the shell are often wrong; it's a space rife with confidently stated overgeneralizations and misconceptions.

Comment: Yeah ... but there are exceptions like contributors on stackoverflow with extreme high reputation not capable to explain anything in a way which harmonize with my way of understanding, while some new people scored below 1000 provide invaluable enlightening help. You never know ... It's always a bit gambling. Extreme is it in the emacs group ... if you ask a question ... you get a link to documentation punishing you for laziness of not reading it ... I dropped emacs because it's a bunch of crap not worth the investment of improving - in my eyes it needs just a total rewrite from scratch  ...

Comment: The problem with shell redirections and other stuff is that the available documentation is extremely hard for me to read and understand ... not my style ... the reason why I have created the concept of  oOo way of approaching programming and computer interfaces - and face rejection instead of enthusiasm - the mainstream likes to create one more programming language splitting people into smaller and smaller groups  instead of  promoting precise and correct expression of ideas using just English. By the way ChatGPT is a real master of understanding of languages, especially of English .