# How to ensure proper order of single command outputs in a Linux shell (dash, bash) script run by Textadept F5?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, textadept

The described behavior occurs when I am running the code from Textadept text editor F5 (run code) feature (`bash "%f"`) looking at the output in the output buffer. I can't reproduce it when running the script from the Terminal shell ... (thanks to *Charles Duffy* for pointing it out in the comments).

My current work around is to use `sleep`, but the amount of time is deliberately chosen and the approach may randomly fail no matter which value is used in sleep.
Any idea how to assure the right order, so that the outcome of the `output()` function always for sure appears between `-- 1 --` and `-- 2 --` ?

```
output() { echo stdout;  echo stderr >&2; }
echo ' --1-- ' 
output  3>&2    1>&2    2>&3 
#sleep 0.001    # still causes the outcome of output be printed after echo '--2--'
sleep 0.01      # causes outcome of output be printed after echo '--1--'
echo ' --2-- '
```

Output to achieve:

```
 --1-- 
stdout
stderr
 --2--
```

Output without `sleep` or with too small sleep value:

```
 --1-- 
 --2-- 
stdout
stderr
```

Comment: Don't split them. Ordering is nondeterministic if and only if the FDs are not duplicates of each other. That is to say, the moment you do something like `exec >(tee stdout.log) 2>(tee stderr.log >&2)` (or a more POSIXy equivalent thereto), you've thrown away any chance of having deterministic ordering between stdout and stderr.

Comment: ...which is to say, you aren't showing enough code here to reproduce the problem; if you run the code given in this question starting with both stdout and stderr pointing to the same descriptor, this code _will_ have robustly reliable behavior.

Comment: Run the code with and without sleep ... with sleep you will see the lines `stdout \n stderr` between 1 and 2, and without sleep after `--1--` and `--2--`. The code is sufficient to reproduce the issue,

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an online sandbox (https://repl.it/ or the like) where you repro the problem with only the code given here? I can't make it happen.

Comment: Mind, stdout and stderr have different buffering behaviors by default (when both are redirected to a TTY), so stderr being flushed more quickly than stdout would be normal in a lot of languages, but a call to `echo` in bash flushes when it completes, so that's not the case here.

Comment: Again, I _always_ get `1` `stdout` `stderr` `2`, even with no `sleep` at all. To produce anything different, you need to be running in an environment where stdout and stderr have been subject to redirections that mean they're no longer duplicative of each other.

Comment: See the updated question ... I haven't yet seen the reversed order of stdout and stderr outputs ... not aware also this can be in the wrong order. My issue is that I would like to see the outcome between the separator lines, not after ...

Comment: I've seen your update, but again, it's claiming output that I can't repro. If we can't see the problem ourselves, we can't root-cause it or propose fixes.

Comment: (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760692/separately-redirecting-and-recombining-stderr-stdout-without-losing-ordering for discussion of the case where someone _is_ splitting and recombining the streams)

Comment: I have checked it in a Terminal shell ... and I can't reproduce this behavior in the xfce4-terminal Terminal running bash either, so I have edited the question to give further details about the observed behavior.

Comment: The easy answer is probably to force the FDs back to being duplicates of each other. Put `exec 2>&1` or `exec >&2` at the top of your script, ugly as it is, and then you'll be in a state where POSIX guarantees ordering. This does mean that whatever functionality TextAdept is relying on this split to provide (color highlighting differently between stdout and stderr?) won't work.

Comment: Wow! It works ... may you provide an answer and explain in detail how does it make a difference and why? What is the impact of `exec 2>&1` causing the right order of outputs in Textadept and how did it come that it was not in the right order in first place? Should every shell script start with `exec 2>&1` to avoid problems with running it from some IDE environment?

Comment: Textadept for the GUI version rely on Qt's or Gtk's process spawning features, and for the Terminal version polls manually (the easiest maintenance-wise for the maintainer of the project ). SciTE output buffer works OK like Terminals do.

Comment: _Should every shell script start with `exec 2>&1` to avoid problems...?_ -- I wouldn't recommend that. `2>&1` (redirecting stderr to stdout) papers over the differences between stderr and stdout in a way that does damage when you _need_ those differences -- for example, when you're writing content that should go through a pipeline or into a data file / output file to stdout, and content that should be presented directly to the user to stderr.

Comment: (on the other hand, if _everything_ you write is intended for human consumption, and none of it is meant to go to disk or be piped to another program, just write everything to stderr and the problem is moot; similarly, if everything you write is output proper -- in the sense of being the content your program exists to create, as opposed to logs/status/diagnostics/prompts/etc -- just write all that content to stdout, and again problem solved).

Comment: You didn't say which OS you are using, but if it is Linux, consider using `stdbuf` to run your output unbuffered.

Comment: @user1934428 : yes, I am on Linux Mint Xfce and I have tried `stdbuf -o0`  as first measure, but it didn't help having no effect at all, because the reason was not the buffering but delaying of filling the buffer (I deduct it from the fact that sleep command helped to get the right order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing a wrapper script that combines stdout and stderr, and running your scripts behind that wrapper when you're using a tool like Textadept that reads those streams separately and then recombines them.

For example, if you create a script, saved in a location on your PATH under the name `on-stdout` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1  # make FD 2 (stderr) point to what's currently on FD 1 (stdout)
exec "$@"  # replace ourselves with the script named by our arguments
```

...you could, instead of having Textadept run `./yourscript arg1 arg2`, tell it to run `on-stdout ./yourscript arg1 arg2`. This would make the stderr handle received by `yourscript` *be a copy of the stdout handle*; because both descriptors point to the same handle, the operating system will then guarantee that write order is preserved.

Comment: How to tell Textadept the right path to the file? %f will be replaced by the current script file name, but the current working directory gets lost on the way to the target script ...

Comment: `exec "$(pwd)/$@" ` does the trick ... preserving the current working directory

Comment: Um, no. The working directory **is** inherited by subprocesses, so `on-stdout ./yourscript arg1 arg2` would work -- just as you need `./` to run `./yourscript`, you still need it when wrapped with `on-stdout`.. The problem you're having is rather that `.` isn't in the default PATH (for very good, security-centric reasons).

Comment: @Claudio, `$(pwd)` is generally an antipattern -- it's _much_ slower to execute than just evaluating `$PWD`, and the results differ only in deeply unusual corner cases. More immediately relevant, _either_ `"$(pwd)/$@"` or `"$PWD/$@"` will introduce bugs when `$0` was already an absolute path.

Comment: I can't accept the answer without at least a hint about the issue with the working directory because the code does not work with Textadept failing with "scriptFileName not found" ...

Comment: @Claudio, accordingly, I've changed the examples to use `./yourscript` everywhere they previously said `yourscript`.